# Authentication error in Cloud JIRA REST API using asp.net (C#)?

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on a requirement where I want to upload the multiple test cases into JIRA. We are using the cloud JIRA hence we are using the JIRA rest API for cloud. I am new into API integration hence not sure how to accomplish my task. However I write few lines of code login connection:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to a Jira Example application!");
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();
        JiraManager manager = new JiraManager(username, password);
        manager.RunQuery(JiraResource.project, null, null, "GET");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public enum JiraResource
    {
        project
    }

    public class JiraManager
    {

        private const string m_BaseUrl = "https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session";
        private string m_Username;
        private string m_Password;

        public JiraManager(string username, string password)
        {
            m_Username = username;
            m_Password = password;
        }

        public string RunQuery(string argument, string data, string method)
        {
            argument = null;
            data = null;
            method = "GET";
            return RunQuery(argument, data, method);
        }


        public void RunQuery(JiraResource resource, string argument, string data, string method)
        {
            string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", m_BaseUrl, resource.ToString());

            if (argument != null)
            {
                url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", url, argument);
            }

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = method;

            if (data != null)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(data);
                }
            }

            string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            string result = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private string GetEncodedCredentials()
        {
            string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", m_Username, m_Password);
            byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
        }
    }
```

However When I am running the above code, I got the following error:

> the remote server returned an error (404)

But few time back I was getting the different error by executing the same code:

> the remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized.

I tried different work arounds but all went in vain. May I know why this error is coming? What could be the resolution of this error?

Comment: What is the URL? Shouldn't the format be  `"{0}/{1}/"` either? Your base URL for the second go is wrong too.

Comment: Thanks patrick. It's working now.